# Convert nginx rules to .htacees

Tags: nginx, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

I am trying to convert my nginx blocks to apache(.htaccess) file but not able to achive it. Can you please help me with this

```
location = /index.php {
  if ($arg_a = get) {
    return 301 /$arg_a/$arg_b;
  }
}

location = /home.php {
 return 301 /$arg_bool;
}
```

for the action = get, here is what the legacy website url looked like:

> /index.php?action=get&id=5000849

(the code above rewrites to/get/5000849)

Comment: What is `$arg_bool` referring to in the second `location` block?

Comment: `home.php?bool=contact`  will redirect to /contact

Answer (score 1):

> (the code above rewrites to/get/5000849)

The above Nginx code is an *external (301) redirect*, not strictly a "rewrite". (Although you will most probably need a rewrite as well later in your `.htaccess` file.)

To *redirect* `/index.php?action=get&id=5000849` to `/get/5000849` in `.htaccess` you would do something like the following near the top of your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^action=(get)&id=(\d+)
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /%1/%2 [R=302,L]
```

The `get` part could have been hardcoded, instead of using a backreference, since that appears to be constant. Although using a backreference saves repetition (which would be my preference).

The check against the `REDIRECT_STATUS` environment variable is to avoid a redirect loop, as I *assume* you already have a directive that *rewrites* the request back to `index.php` later in your config file. (?)

`%1` and `%2` are backreferences to the captured groups in the last matched *CondPattern* (preceding `RewriteCond` directive).

This redirect should only be used to redirect an old URL structure in order to maintain SEO. This should not be integral to your site functionality.

NB: Test with 302 (temporary) redirects to avoid caching issues. And only change to 301 (permanent) when you are sure it's working OK. You will need to clear your browser cache before testing.

> **UPDATE:** `home.php?bool=contact` will redirect to `/contact`

For the second part, the same principle applies, except there is just one URL parameter instead of two. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^bool=([a-z]+)
RewriteRule ^home\.php$ /%1 [R=302,L]
```

This assumes `<contact>` in your example is always a-z (lowercase) - as in your example. Adjust the regex `[a-z]+` as required.

Comment: How we check `location = /index.php { }` in apache? as you see, I have `index.php` and `home.php` different and I am handling them differently

Comment: Essentially, `RewriteRule ^index\.php$ .....` in `.htaccess`.

Comment: `location = /home.php {
 return 301 /home/$arg_bool;
}` how do we handle this part?

Comment: I've updated my answer. Your question and comment (to your question) does not include `/home` in the target URL, so I've gone with that version.

Comment: How did you get on with this?